# Как открыть проект от 3.3.2 в 2.3.3 Андроид студио

Tags: android-studio

Возможно ли открыть проект версии `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'` в версии `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`?

Comment: мне кажется можно будет, только предложат обновить градл и могут некоторые библиотеки конфликтовать

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko- Я так понимаю придётся всё таки обновить андроид студио до 3.3.2

Comment: а вам не хочется я так понимаю?)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko- Да , имел печальный опыт обновления андроид студии. Пришлось откат делать на прежнюю . Но а теперь один проект требует новой версии.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko- Не подскажите , будут ли конфликты после обновления с импортом проектов от прошлой версии ..?

Comment: не должно, все подтягивается, я вам советую обновится, они баги чинят и жизнь будет лучше))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko- Спасибо за совет. Буду обновляться.

Comment: Так это вроде версия gradle, а не АС. Какой версии АС роли особо не играет.